# how to use JWTTokenUserAuthentication backend experimental feature in djangorestframework-simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, microservices, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am planning to create microservices architecture in Django and Django rest framework. My intent is to have a separate Django project that handles authentication. This project has `djangorestframework-simplejwt` package which mentions an SSO feature [here](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/experimental_features.html).

How do I implement this? Should I update the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in both the django projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES to 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTTokenUserAuthentication' in both Django projects. Then your SIMPLE_JWT settings in authentication project should look like this:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    ...

    'SIGNING_KEY': config('SECRET_KEY'),
    'VERIFYING_KEY': config('SECRET_KEY'),

    ...
}
```

While the SIMPLE_JWT for your other service should look like this:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    ...

    'SIGNING_KEY': 'AUTHENTICATION PROJECT SECRET KEY',
    'VERIFYING_KEY': 'AUTHENTICATION PROJECT SECRET KEY',

    ...
}
```

In my case, I stored the SECRET_KEY as an environment variable.